# Imagem quebrada no laravel 5.6 [homestead]

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, nginx, laravel-blade, homestead

Subi para minha aplicação uma imagem quando usava o php artisan serve,
hoje estou utilizando o homestead, quando fui olhar a aplicação barrou minha url e não deixa ser exibida.

```
<img src="/storage/avatars/{{ Auth::user()->imagem }}" />
```

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor a parte em que diz "aplicação barrou minha url"? Verificou nas ferramentas de desenvolvedor do navegador o que aconteceu?

Comment: Oi @AndersonCarlosWoss, tentei acessar a uri completa e deu erro: https://validacaolaravel.dev/storage/avatars/20180805-172903Fernando_Carvalho_Santana.jpeg

Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Isto seria feito no nginx?

Comment: Reavalie as suas perguntas. Em nenhuma vc marcou uma resposta como a certa, o que foge do padrão do site.

Comment: Onde avalio @sam

Comment: No seu "Perfil" tem seu histórico de perguntas. É só entrar em cada uma e ver se alguma resposta resolveu o problema e marcar ela.